# Mapping fields from swagger generated enum to entity enum in Java

Tags: enums, openapi

This is a class which is created to mapping

```
    @Column(name = "gender")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;
```

Gender enum type created in local to map.

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE,
    FEMALE,
    OTHER
}
```

swagger.yml

```
 gender:
   type: string
   enum:
     - MALE
     - FEMALE
     - OTHERS
```

This is mapper class

```
@Component
public class GuestMapper {
    public GuestsEntity convertToGuestEntity(Guest guest) {
        GuestsEntity newGuests = new GuestsEntity();
            newGuests.setGender(guest.getGender());

}
```

[image: screenshot of error]

I checked all the fields from entity and also checked from generated class. but didnt see any difference. Any help?